# Глубина рекурсии на вычисление оптимального сбора кубика Рубика

Tags: алгоритм, рекурсия

Какой глубины рекурсии, в теории, достаточно для вычисления оптимального пути сбора Кубика Рубика?

Конечно, для его сбора существуют специальные алгоритмы и все такое. Но хотелось бы знать, чисто перебором всех возможных операций над кубиком каковой глубины рекурсии будет достаточно для его сбора? К примеру, допустить существование 17-20 ходового пути.

Answer (score 4):

На Википедии [написано](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0):

> Наконец в августе 2010 года группа под
> руководством профессора Морли
> Дэвидсона сообщила, что, используя
> свободное от обработки поисковых
> запросов машинное время одного из
> суперкомпьютеров Google Inc., им
> удалось доказать, что из любого
> положения кубик Рубика можно собрать
> не более, чем за 20 ходов. Однако
> этот результат пока ещё не проверен.

Поэтому глубина рекурсии, скорее всего, не превосходит 20-ти, и в худшем случая она достигается.

Comment: То что есть алгоритм, с помощью которого можно собрать кубик за 20 ходов, еще не значит, что в процессе его поиска не встретится тупиковых ветвей с бОльшим количеством ходов (или выигрышных алгоритмов опять же с большим количеством ходов).

Comment: Так по-моему четко написано, что если мы вышли за 20 ходов + эпсилон, то эту ветвь решения можно уже сразу не рассматривать. Потому что будет более короткое решение.

Answer (score 0):

Взять один из оптимальных алгоритмов и посчитать его худший случай, благо размер входных данных известен.